# Is it possible to increase the allowed UV attempts on a YubiKey

Tags: yubikey

Using the YubiKey FIDO2 functionality the fingerprint validation is prone to failing validation despite using an enrolled fingerprint.  Is there anyway to increase the preferred_platform_uv_attempts so the credential doesn't become blocked after only 3 attempts?

I'm using the python libraries, but it seems it is only possible to get this variable, but not set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of retries for UV is defined by `maxUvRetries`.

From the [CTAP2 spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-ps-20210615/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-ps-errata-20220621.html#maxuvretries):

> maxUvRetries is a global value statically configured into an authenticator; it is the maximum number of retries that a user can experience. uvRetries is initialized to this value. Its value MUST be in the range of 1 to 25, inclusive.

So this value is set by the manufacturer, and cannot be changed.